# Snowflake to google cloud storage - bucket security

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are looking at this link that outlines how to stage Snowflake output to a GCS bucket  (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-gcs-config.html).  In step 3 of the article, you simply provide the name of the service account to the GCS bucket and once assigned with the right permissions, the snowflake account can obtain access.

My question is, if the name of that service account were compromised, what is stopping a potential hacker from impersonating that account and running a python/java program to connect to my GCS bucket where that account is allowed?

In that article, I don't see any requirement for keys, tokens, certs or other additional controls to restrict access.  On the GCP side, it is just permissions and the name of the account that controls it?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cool question, and first thing you should know is that your data is safe.

When you want to setup GCP/GCS so Snowflake can read files from it, Snowflake will create a service account id like `paoeffnyz@sfc-prod2-1-947.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. You can use that identity to tell GCS things like "yes, it's fine to share these files of mine with `paoeffnyz@sfc-prod2-1-947.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. This is secure.

Why?

The only one that holds the secrets to identify as `paoeffnyz@sfc-prod2-1-947.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is your Snowflake account. It doesn't matter if this id becomes public, because no one has the "password" for it, other than your Snowflake account.

Comment: Hi Felipe,   thanks for this assurance.   So Snowflake and Google are exchanging authentication information in the background.  Could you point us to any link or documentation that outlines how this is done?   

Also, if we want to use our "own" customized authentication...e.g. short lived credentials, token exchange, IdP, mutual TLS, HSM, etc.   is this something we can control?  Or will Snowflake lock out users from customizing the external storage integration product?

Thanks Felipe.

Comment: This is the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-gcs-config.html

Comment: Hi Felipe,  yes that was the link I posted that was the basis of my original question.  I was hoping you might have other in-depth references that you might have come across that explains the authentication part of it in greater detail.  Thank you.

Comment: That's the best I have. What is a specific thing that could make this documentation better? I can pass the feedback to the team.

Comment: For me the most important part of your question was "if the name of that service account were compromised", and what I can assure you is that the name of that account was made public, that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hi Felipe,   this is fine...the explanation is satisfactory.  I will mark this question as answered.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Thanks! The beautiful thing is that you can give that service account id to anyone in the world, and they can use it to give read permissions to your Snowflake account into their GCP assets.